# Is there any way to inject logic on every query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, dbcontext

I'm trying to store all dates in UTC, but retrieve them according to the timezone specified by a user in app settings using Entity Framework DbContext.

I have no issues with that when I store values in database because I can override SaveChanges. But I got stuck with converting all dates after its retrieval.

I've tryied to use `ObjectMaterialized` event:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized += ObjectMaterialized; 
private static void ObjectMaterialized(object sender, ObjectMaterializedEventArgs args)
{
    //Here is my convertion
}
```

It works perfectly when I retrieve whole entities from db for example:

```
var task = db.Tasks.FirstOrDefault();
```

But when I do any projections for example:

```
var task = db.Tasks.Select(t => new { t.DueDate })
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Then the entities are not materialized and event don't get fired.

Could anyone suggest me some way to archieve the goal I described above?

Comment: Why? Why not retrieve them in UTC and only convert them for display?

Comment: Good question. I think that I have done mistake thinking that I should perform business logic in local time. Now I realize that it's not right because of DTS.

Comment: One more thing that gave me idea to ask this question is that EF specifies DateTimeKind as Unspecified. It would be nice to have some workaround that could set it as DateTimeKind.Utc just after query executes instead of puting this logic all across app.